# Paso de parámetros en modal y jquery

Tags: php, jquery, modal

Estoy trabajando con un `dropdown` y dependiendo del `item` que selecciones va a abrir un modal. El cual tiene que contener, el ID, el ID de lo que se selecciona y un texto.

Este es el `drop`:

```
<?php foreach ($estadosinc as $estados):
                    if ($estados->id_estado_incidencia != 1 && $estados->id_estado_incidencia !=4){  ?>
                      <a class="dropdown-item cambiaestado" href="#" data-idinc="<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>" data-drop="<?php echo $estados->id_estado_incidencia; ?>"><?php echo $estados->nombre_estado_incidencia ?></a>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="dropdown-item" data-idinc="<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>" data-drop="<?php echo $estados->id_estado_incidencia; ?>" data-target="#terminar-incidencia-<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>" ><?php echo $estados->nombre_estado_incidencia ?></a>
                    <?php  }  endforeach ?>
```

y este es el `modal`:

```
<div class="modal" id="terminar-incidencia-<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Agrega descripción de la incidencia</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                        <textarea name="justificar" id="justificar" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
                      <button data="<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-terminar-incidencia">Guardar Cambios</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

El problema es que no me trae bien los datos, en el `jquery`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-terminar-incidencia', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var drop = $(this).data('drop');
    var idinc = $(this).data('idinc');
    var value = $('#justificar').val();
    alert(drop);
    var action = base_url + 'Incidencia/terminarIncidencia/' + idinc + '/' + drop + '/' + value;
    var method = 'post';
    var data = null;
```

Copio la primer parte únicamente por que el `ajax` no importa.

Comment: es por que llamas mal a $(this).data('drop'); y  var idinc = $(this).data('idinc'); fijate que estas usando $(document).on('click', '.btn-terminar-incidencia',  en ningun momento llamas a $("a .dropdown-item")

Comment: No entiendo como usaria entonces para llamar al .btn-terminar-incidencia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

es por que llamas mal a `$(this).data('drop');` y `var idinc = $(this).data('idinc');` fijate que estas usando `$(document).on('click', '.btn-terminar-incidencia'`, en ningun momento llamas a `$("a .dropdown-item")`

aquí un ejemplo.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-item', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var drop = $(this).data('drop');
    var idinc = $(this).data('idinc');
    var value = $('#justificar').val();
    alert(drop);
    /*var action = base_url + 'Incidencia/terminarIncidencia/' + idinc + '/' + drop + '/' + value;
    var method = 'post';
    var data = null;*/
    
    $(".modal label").html('ID:'+idinc+'  -  Estado:'+drop);
    $(".modal").modal('show');
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<div class="dropdown btn-terminar-incidencia">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-idinc="1" data-drop="id_estado_incidencia" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-idinc="2" data-drop="id_estado_incidencia" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-idinc="3" data-drop="id_estado_incidencia" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="terminar-incidencia-<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Agrega descripción de la incidencia</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                  <label></label><br>
                        <textarea name="justificar" id="justificar" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
                      <button data="<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-terminar-incidencia">Guardar Cambios</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```